# Using whereDate on Laravel query from joined table

Tags: mysql, laravel, php-carbon

I've got two tables in my SQL database. Both have a `period_from` column as the common date format. Both tables have data back dating for several weeks, I've joined my tables, and am selecting the appropriate columns that I need.

Everything works great and gives me the correct data, but as soon as I add `whereDate()` I get nothing, an empty array. I've tried the bogstandard `where()` and have also tried targetting my table followed by my column, e.g: `*.period_from`, not sure why it's not giving me any results here.

```php
$from = Carbon::now()->subDays(14);
$to = Carbon::now();
$order = 'asc';

$data = DB::table('data_source_one as DGA')
      ->join('data_source_two as DLCA', 'DGA.created_at', '=', 'DLCA.created_at')
      ->where('event_action', 'Step 1 Loaded: (Loan Details)')
      ->select('event_count', 'sessions', 'leads', 'DGA.created_at', 'DGA.period_from', 'DGA.period_to')
      ->whereDate('DGA.period_from', '>=', $from)
      ->whereDate('DGA.period_to', '<=', $to)
      ->orderBy('DGA.created_at', $order)
      ->get();
```

Comment: What is the SQL type of `period_from`?

Answer (score 1):

you can just do this :

```
$from = Carbon::now()->subDays(14);
$to = Carbon::now();
$order = 'asc';

$data = DB::table('data_source_one as DGA')
      ->join('data_source_two as DLCA', 'DGA.created_at', '=', 'DLCA.created_at')
      ->where('event_action', 'Step 1 Loaded: (Loan Details)')
      ->select('event_count', 'sessions', 'leads', 'DGA.created_at', 'DGA.period_from', 'DGA.period_to')
      ->where('DGA.period_from', '>=', $from)
      ->where('DGA.period_to', '<=', $to)
      ->orderBy('DGA.created_at', $order)
      ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks, it actually looks like my query is working, just didn't have any data for a certain number of data so it wasn't able to fetch any data, thanks! :)